# add Node from Queue into list but its makes infinite loop

Tags: python, nodes, priority-queue

I have the maze:

[image]

I want to add **Node (state, action)** from **Queue** into `states = []` without **popup all Node in Queue**

```
count = 0
max_element = queue.count()
        for node in queue.queue_to_add_again():
            if count < max_element:
                states.append((node.state, node.action))
                queue.add(node)
                count += 1
            else:
                break
```

I have problem with infinite loop and cannot solve this maze. Someone can help me?

queue.count():

```
def count(self):
    return len(self.queue)
```

queue.queue_to_add_again():

```
def queue_to_add_again(self):
    return self.queue
```

Comment: As written your question is very confusing.  Please clarify your problem by (1) Defining what you are trying to do in logical terms, (2) Clarify what you mean by "without popup all Node in Queue". (3) Provide input data and expected output. (4) Explain the purpose of ```states``` variable.